# Kotest - Generate exhaustive object permutations with no repeat

Tags: kotlin, kotest

I want to be able to generate an exhaustive permutation of objects. Imagine the following object

```
data class Person (name: String, age: Int)
```

For testing purposes, I want to restrict the `name` to `3` values. `Mohammad`, `Nasir`, `Rasul` and `age` to `4` values. `10`, `20`, `30`, `40`. I want to generate 12 objects, where each name has each of the 4 ages.

I can generate an `arbitrary` binding, however that doesn't gurantee `12` iterations will each have a unique object. I have to increase the iteration count, and weed out duplicates.

```
    val list = Arb.bind(
        listOf("Nasir", "Rasul", "Mohammad").exhaustive(),
        listOf(10, 20, 30, 40).exhaustive()
    ) { name, age -> Person(name, age) }

    "Test person " - {
        runBlocking {
            list.checkAll(12) {
                System.out.println("Testing $it")
                assertTrue(it.age < 50)
            }
        }
    }
```

Looking in the source code, I can't seem to find a way. I am hoping someone in the community has had a need for this.

Thanks.

Note: I am looking for a way with `Exhaustive` generator, not the `Arb` generator. I *could* do some post processing and remove duplicates, but I am hoping for something more reliably unique upfront.

```
Example outout:

Testing Person(name=Mohammad, age=40)
Testing Person(name=Nasir, age=20)
Testing Person(name=Rasul, age=20)
Testing Person(name=Rasul, age=30)
Testing Person(name=Mohammad, age=20)
Testing Person(name=Rasul, age=40)
Testing Person(name=Nasir, age=10)
Testing Person(name=Rasul, age=10)
Testing Person(name=Nasir, age=40)
Testing Person(name=Rasul, age=40)
Testing Person(name=Nasir, age=30)
Testing Person(name=Mohammad, age=30)
```

Notice the `Rasul:40` is duplicated. `Mohammad:10` missed out.

1 possible solution based on @Tenfour04's comment is to use `times` and `map`. Though with my fields, the mapping becomes hairy, as we'll have `Pairs` and `Pairs` and `Pairs` to process.

```
    "Test cross product" - {
        val times = Exhaustive.collection(listOf("Nasir", "Rasul"))
            .times(Exhaustive.collection(listOf(10, 20)))
            .map { Person(it.first as String, it.second) }
        runBlocking {
            times.checkAll(4) {
                println("$it")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064837/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-test-all-permutations-with-kotest-property-based-testi

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04. Not quite. I want to be able to define this in the context of object, and the linked construct seems outside. I'll give it a try though, but at first glance I don't think it will work. I'll report back, if I find results to the contrary.

Comment: I think it'll work. I just needed to `map` it to an object.. Thanks @Tenfour04. With more than 2 properties though, it starts becoming convoluted due to use of `Pair`.

Comment: Wy not just generate all possible combinations manually `val persons = names.flatMap { name -> ages.map { Person(name, it) } }`?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь I am not certain I follow. I will have a data structure which will have a different set of values for each attribute, some enums, some other finite set ... and if I understand you correctly, your suggestion would work if it was only two things ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by just mapping over each of the values in each component and combining them into a new Exhaustive. For example, if you have three components you want to generate all the combinations for:

```
fun <A, B, C, D> cartesian(
   a: Exhaustive<A>,
   b: Exhaustive<B>,
   c: Exhaustive<C>,
   f: (A, B, C) -> D
): Exhaustive<D> {
   val ds = a.values.flatMap { _a ->
      b.values.flatMap { _b ->
         c.values.map { _c ->
            f(_a, _b, _c)
         }
      }
   }
   return ds.exhaustive()
}
```

Then that exhaustive can be used in a test (And so on for arity-2 etc).

Here is how you would use it for your persons example.

```
val persons = cartesian(
   Exhaustive.collection(listOf("Nasir", "Rasul")),
   Exhaustive.collection(listOf(10, 20))
) { a, b -> Person(a, b) }

checkAll(persons) { person -> .... test here .... }
```

Note: The above function exists in Kotest 4.5 which at time of writing hasn't been released.  https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/master/kotest-property/src/commonMain/kotlin/io/kotest/property/exhaustive/cartesian.kt